# Fastest way to sample most numbers with minimum difference larger than a value from a Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, random

Given a list of 20 float numbers, I want to find a largest subset where any two of the candidates are different from each other larger than a `mindiff = 1.`. Right now I am using a brute-force method to search from largest to smallest subsets using `itertools.combinations`. As shown below, the code finds a subset after 4 s for a list of 20 numbers.

```
from itertools import combinations
import random
from time import time

mindiff = 1.
length = 20
random.seed(99)
lst = [random.uniform(1., 10.) for _ in range(length)]

t0 = time()
n = len(lst)
sample = []
found = False
while not found:
    # get all subsets with size n
    subsets = list(combinations(lst, n))
    # shuffle to ensure randomness
    random.shuffle(subsets)
    for subset in subsets:
        # sort the subset numbers
        ss = sorted(subset)
        # calculate the differences between every two adjacent numbers
        diffs = [j-i for i, j in zip(ss[:-1], ss[1:])]
        if min(diffs) > mindiff:
            sample = set(subset)
            found = True
            break
    # check subsets with size -1
    n -= 1

print(sample)
print(time()-t0)
```

Output:

```
{2.3704888087015568, 4.365818049020534, 5.403474619948962, 6.518944556233767, 7.8388969285727015, 9.117993839791751}
4.182451486587524
```

However, in reality I have a list of 200 numbers, which is infeasible for a brute-froce enumeration. I want a fast algorithm to sample just one **random** **largest** subset with a minimum difference larger than 1. Note that I want each sample has randomness and maximum size. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sample the list and pick elements that differ by more than 1.0 to build the set instead?

Comment: @rdas Yes. The subset numbers must be different from each other so it must be a set. But this is not important anyways.

Comment: It seems the answer already posted is sufficient. It takes into the consideration that the smallest value in the set will always be present in the largest subset. Hence take every value afterwards that is greater than 1

Comment: @Onyambu Yes now I understand it is sufficient but I completely forgot that my purpose is to sample randomly! I just emphasized it in my question. My bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My previous answer assumed you simply wanted a single optimal solution, not a uniform random sample of all solutions. This answer assumes you want one that samples uniformly from all such optimal solutions.

1. Construct a directed acyclic graph `G` where there is one node for each point, and nodes `a` and `b` are connected when `b - a > mindist`. Also add two virtual nodes, `s` and `t`, where `s -> x` for all `x` and `x -> t` for all `x`.
2. Calculate for each node in `G` how many paths of length `k` exist to `t`. You can do this efficiently in `O(n^2 k)` time using dynamic programming with a table `P[x][k]`, filling initially `P[x][0] = 0` except `P[t][0] = 1`, and then `P[x][k] = sum(P[y][k-1] for y in neighbors(x))`.

   Keep doing this until you reach the maximum `k` - you now know the size of the optimal subset.
3. Uniformly sample a path  of length `k` from `s` to `t` using `P` to weight your choices.

   This is done by starting at `s`. We then look at each neighbor of `s` and choose one randomly with a weighting dictated by `P[s][k]`. This gives us our first element of the optimal set.

   We then repeatedly perform this step. We are at `x`, look at the neighbors of `x` and pick one randomly using weights `P[x][k-i]` where `i` is the step we're at.
4. Use the nodes you sampled in 3 as your random subset.

An implementation of the above in pure Python:

```
import random

def sample_mindist_subset(xs, mindist):
    # Construct directed graph G.
    n = len(xs)
    s = n; t = n + 1  # Two virtual nodes, source and sink.
    neighbors = {
        i: [t] + [j for j in range(n) if xs[j] - xs[i] > mindist]
        for i in range(n)}
    neighbors[s] = [t] + list(range(n))
    neighbors[t] = []

    # Compute number of paths P[x][k] from x to t of length k.
    P = [[0 for _ in range(n+2)] for _ in range(n+2)]
    P[t][0] = 1
    for k in range(1, n+2):
        for x in range(n+2):
            P[x][k] = sum(P[y][k-1] for y in neighbors[x])

    # Sample maximum length path uniformly at random.
    maxk = max(k for k in range(n+2) if P[s][k] > 0)
    path = [s]
    while path[-1] != t:
        candidates = neighbors[path[-1]]
        weights = [P[cn][maxk-len(path)] for cn in candidates]
        path.append(random.choices(candidates, weights)[0])

    return [xs[i] for i in path[1:-1]]
```

Note that if you want to sample from the same set of numbers many times, you don't have to recompute `P` every single time and can re-use it.

Comment: @Shaun Han "I am trying to understand the purpose of the two virtual nodes." The purpose of the virtual nodes is that you don't know what the first or last element of the subset will be, but by adding the two virtual nodes that are connected to everything you know that the maximum path length is exactly two longer, and any maximum length path always starts on `s` and ends on `t`. You could see it as if I temporarily added `-inf` and `inf` to the input list so I always know where I start/end, and strip them again at the end.

Comment: I think I kinda understand now. This solution is brilliant. I tested on my 200-number list but it always generates a same subset. I don't know if it's because my list only has one solution. Do you have a list (or seed) that can generate different subsets when you tested?

Comment: @ShaunHan Try for example `sample_mindist_subset(np.linspace(0, 10, 20), 1)`. By the way `P[s][maxk]` is the total number of solutions.

Comment: this is actually quite an ingenious solution, cudos @orlp

Answer (score 7):

I probably don't fully understand the question, because right now the solution is quite trivial. EDIT: yes, I misunderstood after all, the OP does not just want an optimal solution, but wishes to **randomly sample from the set of optimal solutions**. This answer is not incorrect but it also is an answer to a different question than what OP is interested in.

---

Simply sort the numbers and greedily construct the subset:

```
def mindist_subset(xs, mindist):
    result = []
    for x in sorted(xs):
        if not result or x - result[-1] > mindist:
            result.append(x)
    return result
```

---

Sketch of proof of correctness.

Suppose we have a solution `S` given input array `A` that is of optimal size. If it does not contain `min(A)` note that we could remove `min(S)` from `S` and add `min(A)` since this would only increase the distance between `min(S)` and the second smallest number in `S`. Conclusion: we can without loss of generality assume that `min(A)` is part of an optimal solution.

Now we can apply this argument recursively. We add `min(A)` to a solution and remove all elements too close to `min(A)`, giving remaining elements `A'`. Then we're left with a subproblem where exactly the same argument applies, we can choose `min(A')` as our next element of the solution, etc.

Comment: This cannot guarantee a largest subset.

Comment: @ShaunHan I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: @fthomson `mindist_subset([2.6092208852795107, 2.8006790011745086, 4.447608238289605], 1)` returns `[2.6092208852795107, 4.447608238289605]` as desired.

Comment: @ShaunHan can you prove the incorrectness of this? Because this is solution is actually correct

Comment: I always hesitate to use a greedy approach since I think it will not always find the largest subset. Can you prove the correctness of this?

Comment: @ShaunHan Added a quick proof sketch of correctness.

Comment: @ShaunHan Your problem becomes a lot more interesting if you wish to sample uniformly at random from all optimal subsets, which was one possible interpretation I had of your question when I said "I probably don't fully understand the question".

Comment: @orlp To my understanding, your code doesn't have randomness right? I need randomness!

Comment: @ShaunHan Ah so my suspicion was correct. Yes this answer is deterministic.

Comment: Yes I think I need to make this clear in the question. I don't want to generate a same result every time for a given list.

Comment: @ShaunHan since everything is random, in that case, why cant you generate random numbers that are a mindist apart?

Comment: @Onyambu Of course I have a given list.... Here I just show a random one as an example...

Comment: @ShaunHan I have solved the more interesting problem in my other answer, and now added a Python implementation as well.

Comment: @orlp Thanks! I am digesting your answer btw. I don't have a computer science background so it's a bit overwhelming for me. I am trying to understand the purpose of the two virtual nodes.